# How to determine which files are ignored by a .helmignore file?

Tags: kubernetes, helm, kubernetes-helm

I'm installing a local Helm chart; however, I keep getting an error `Error: UPGRADE FAILED: create: failed to create: Request entity too large: limit is 3145728`. From searching other SO/Stack Exchange questions, this is typically caused by unnecessary files mistakenly included in the chart. The way to resolve this, is to add those entries to a [`.helmignore` file](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/helm_ignore_file/).

My chart has a `.helmignore` file, which should be excluding all unnecessary artifacts within my chart, but I'm still getting the error. So my thought is that my `.helmignore` entries aren't quite targeting the files that they should be.

I've tried running them with the `--debug` flag (didn't show anything more interesting):

```
upgrade.go:139: [debug] preparing upgrade for chartname
upgrade.go:520: [debug] copying values from chartname (v11) to new release.
upgrade.go:147: [debug] performing update for chartname
upgrade.go:319: [debug] creating upgraded release for chartname
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: create: failed to create: Request entity too large: limit is 3145728
helm.go:88: [debug] Request entity too large: limit is 3145728ffff
create: failed to create
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/storage/driver.(*Secrets).Create
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/storage/driver/secrets.go:164
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/storage.(*Storage).Create
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/storage/storage.go:69
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Upgrade).performUpgrade
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/upgrade.go:320
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.(*Upgrade).RunWithContext
        helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/upgrade.go:148
main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:200
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:902
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:87
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_arm64.s:1133
UPGRADE FAILED
main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:202
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:856
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:974
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
        github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.2.1/command.go:902
main.main
        helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:87
runtime.main
        runtime/proc.go:255
runtime.goexit
        runtime/asm_arm64.s:1133
```

I also tried it with the `--dry-run` flag and the chart succeeded. So at this point I'm not sure how to find what's bloating my chart.

How can I tell which files are actually getting ignored (or which are included) when I run a `helm install` or `helm upgrade`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a way, but it might not be the most elegant.

First, we render the chart locally and then use `tree` to print out the subdirectories with their sizes in a human-readable format.

```sh
helm template . --output-dir=file-size-test
tree --du -h file-size-test
```

This produces an output similar to:

```
[340M]  testing123
└── [340M]  chart_name
    ├── [ 91K]  charts
    │   ├── [ 58K]  sub-chart
    │   │   └── [ 58K]  templates
    │   │       ├── [1.3K]  deployment.yaml
    │   │       ├── [ 411]  config.yaml
    │   │       ├── [ 579]  service.yaml
    │   │       └── [ 359]  serviceaccount.yaml
<truncated>
    └── [340M]  templates
        ├── [ 68M]  deployment.yaml
        ├── [136M]  config1.yaml
        ├── [136M]  config2.yaml
        └── [1.3K]  ingress.yaml
```

So now I've found that the issue seems to be the massive `config1.yaml` and `config2.yaml` files.

While this doesn't exactly answer the question of *how* to find which have been ignored, it at least points to which might not have been ignored.